# Appcelerator Studio will not install Android SDKs

Tags: android, sdk, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I am using Appcelerator Studio on Mac OS X

> Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.4.0.201511241829
>
> Build: jenkins-appcelerator-rcp-master-339 (origin/master)
>
> Date: 24 November 2015, 18:30:16
>
> Titanium SDK version 5.1.2.G

I have been trying to install the Android SDK's without success.  I am using the Install from the software under Preferences -> Platforms -> Android

If I browse to the directory with the SDKs I get the error message:

[Android SDK Home] No Android SD...nder the specified SDK location

All the Android SDKs have been loaded by Android Studio so I know they are there.

If I try to install the SDKS through Studio it goes through the motions, downloads and unpacks the files etc and then gives me a completed screen but no sdks is actually saved.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Studio without success

any help is appreciated

Comment: You could try the [4.5 RC of Studio](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/02/release-candidates-for-cli-5-2-titanium-5-2-and-studio-4-5/), but this should work fine with 4.4 as well of course. Could you check what `appc ti info -t android` gives you?

Comment: @Drew what you get with "appc info" or "appc ti info" as asked by Fokke? What issues does it highlight with your android configuration? Also have you Genymotion installed? I think this problem is related to Genymotion (as it happened with me once).

Comment: @muhammad-qasim appc ti info
https://www.dropbox.com/s/co6h06sxht1hh05/appctinfo.txt?dl=0and yes I do have genymotion installed

Comment: @DrewWentzel I think you've a corrupt Appc CLI or Node.js installation. Try completely uninstalling all the tools and installing from scratch. Refer these links for completely wiping out Appcelerator and Node from your machine:  https://archive.appcelerator.com/topic/474/how-do-you-uninstall-titanium-and-appcelerator-studio-completely-and-start-from-scratch     https://gist.github.com/TonyMtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef

Comment: @muhammad-qasim did that, uninstalled everything and then reinstalled studio, nod.js and the cli.  Still had the same issue.  I did not that when I reloaded studio all my titanium projects were there along with the version of the titanium sdk - maybe it didn't delete entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Just give path of your **android-sdk** main directory only. If you are doing correctly then check in that folder having all required folders or not. I attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CADZQ.png) for what folders should be there.

If any of folder missing in mentioned image, it means, your SDK not properly installed. And you need to install it again. you can download SDK from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other

Follow the instruction given in above link and again set path as you were doing before. And install all required SDK using install SDK given in Preferences -> Platforms -> Android.

Comment: Thanks @pooja-lad I have used the android studio to install all the sdks and  verified they all exist see this screen shot:<https://www.dropbox.com/s/oq4cvwp6ev0eejv/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-18%20at%206.28.47%20am.png?dl=0>  Then under  Preferences -> Platforms -> Android path is correct but I still get the error message you can see here<https://www.dropbox.com/s/pss2ykeufelfxns/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-18%20at%206.33.34%20am.png?dl=0>   If I try installing the SDKs in Studio and follow the instructions again it gets to the end downloads everything but i get the SDK not found message.

Comment: Ok.. do one thing first give path any other folder not containing sdk. Click Apply. And then again select right path and just click ok. When next time you will check problem will get solved.

Comment: I faced same issue. if still not work close appcelerator studio and open terminal -> type command **appc logout** and open your appc studio. And give same path.

Comment: @pooja-lad tried changing the location -> apply then select again this did nothing.  I also tried the command line and then restoring , New behaviour I get an error An internal error occurred during: "Update iOS info".
java.lang.NullPointerException and in the devices I only have one iOS device, the android sdks in the dashboard says it's installed but when i check under preferences its not found